# Sharepoint project site template

Tags: 2013, site-template

We want to create a custom site template for our projects. A good idea would be a modification of project site template which is already offered in SharePoint. We are an IT company so have you come across some interesting article about a custom site template used in IT companies?

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: have you come across some interesting article about a custom site template used in IT companies ?